# Manual Mean Filtering

Tags: matlab

Before I begin, I would just like to clarify that I understand how to use kernels and the conv2() function in order to mean filter an image, but I have been tasked with doing this manually by calling up each pixel.

My goal here is to call up each pixel, find its neighbors, average them out, and replace previous values with the acquired mean, without using kernels or conv2(). I have so far attempted to find the neighbors of each pixel using

```
for
   I = 1:512;
     for
        J = 1:683;
A = myimage;
neighbor_offsets = [-1, A, 1, -A, A + 1, -A + 1, -A-1, A - 1];
idx = [I J];
neighbors = bsxfun(@plus,idx,neighbor_offsets);
```

but it does not seem to work, and I am a bit lost in trying to fix it. I think I could finish the job if I were able to get the neighbors by using something like

```
sum(neighbors) / 9
```

then replace the previous values with that answer, but please correct me if I'm. I've developed somewhat of a tendency to ask poor questions, so if anything is unclear, please let me know so I can clarify for you. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example below treats pixels at the edge in the manner that it only considers pixels that are *inside* the image. For example when program is computing average with kernel `dy = (-1:1)` and `dx = (-1:1)` on top-left corner, it only considers top-left corner and its immediate 3 neighbors (right, right-bottom, right), and does average of those 4 pixels.

I would strongly advise you to test every line separately in Matlab's command window to see it's behavior!

```
% find image size
imsz = size( myimage );

% initialize output image
imavg = zeros( imsz );

% iterate over pixels
for yy = 1 : imsz(1)
    for xx = 1 : imsz(2)

        % define rectangle-kernel width
        dy = (-1:1);    % 1 up, to 1 down and ...
        dx = (-1:1);    % 1 left, to 1 right from current pixel

        % get indexes of image
        indy = yy + dy;
        indx = xx + dx;

        % [!!!] keep indexes that are inside image
        indy = indy( indy>0 & indy<=imsz(1) );
        indx = indx( indx>0 & indx<=imsz(2) );

        % create all the pairings of chosen indexes
        [ IY, IX ] = meshgrid( indy, indx );

        % take all values of chosen pixels
        pixs = myimage( sub2ind(imsz,IY(:),IX(:)) );

        % save mean of chosen pixels to the given location
        imavg(yy,xx) = mean( pixs );
    end
end
```

---

You can create function from the above code with creating `mean_filter.m` file with this contents:

```
function imagv = mean_filter( myimage )

    % code from above ...
```

You can call function from command window by positioning yourself in the directory where it's at and executing `filtered = mean_filter( myimage );`.

---

You can repeatedly filter the same image with:

```
filtered_3_times = myimage;
for ii = 1 : 3
    filtered_3_times = mean_filter( filtered_3_times );
end
```

Comment: Appreciate you taking the time to answer my question, but I am totally confused by your code, what exactly is the end result of doing this?

Comment: End result is contained in `imavg`. The way you should test this code is to go to Matlab's console and type one after another and observe results: **1.** `imsz = size( myimage )` **2.** `imavg = zeros( imsz );` **3.** `yy = 1` **4.** `xx = 1` **5.** `dy = (-1:1)` **6.** `dx = (-1:1)` **7.** `indy = yy + dy` **8.** `indx = xx + dx` etc. Don't put `;` at the end of a command to see results and observe partial results from every step of calculation.

Comment: Your code worked perfectly, thank  you sir. Small thing, what would i need to add if I wanted to run the mean filter again? as in average the new values with the same method? Cannot seem to find any "repeat" function in matlab.

Comment: You would have to save that code as a *script*, or *function*. I would advise saving it as a function. I'll add it in the answer...

Comment: sorry, i was unclear. I understand how scripts work, I was looking instead to create a script/function that ran the mean filter several times over and over again on an image. Adding in a loop of some kind that could be controlled is what im looking for.

Comment: @Zoran_Plesivčak im getting an error "function definitions are not permitted in this context", what is it saying here? Again, sorry for all the questions, but im rather new at this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31775/discussion-between-zoran-plesivcak-and-user2475404)